# Axios error when making high volume API calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios, backend

I'm trying to make API calls from localhost using axios within a loop the problem is sometimes it works fine but majority of error occurs.

```
cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '::1',
    port: 8000
  }
```

or this error

```
cause: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT xx:xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxx
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
    errno: -4039,
    code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: 'xx:xxxx::xxx:xxxx:xxx',
    port: 443
  }
```

Making request to this endpoint:

```
app.get("/initialize-db", async (req, res) => {
  const response = await axios
    .get("http://localhost:8000/symbol-list")
    .catch(errorHandler);

  const recordCoiCexUrl = "http://localhost:8000/record-coi-cex";

  const symList = response.data;
  const requests = symList.map((element) => {
    axios.get(`${recordCoiCexUrl}/${element}`);
  });

  await axios.all(requests).catch(errorHandler);

  res.send("Initialize the database");
});
```

endpoint /record-coi-cex is like this:

```
app.get("/record-coi-cex/:symbol", async (req, res) => {
  const symbol = req.params.symbol;
  const url = "https://webapi.niftytrader.in/webapi/option/fatch-option-chain";

  const response = await axios
    .get(url, {
      params: { symbol: symbol },
    })
    .catch(errorHandler);

  //* creating mongoose model with collection name same as symbol
  const Symbol = mongoose.model(symbol, oiDataSchema, symbol);

  //* parsing response from api to get the option data
  const opDatas = response.data.resultData.opDatas;

  //* important vaiables required
  const spot = opDatas[0].index_close;

  opDatas.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.strike_price < b.strike_price;
  });

  const atmIndex = opDatas.findIndex((obj) => obj.strike_price > spot);
  let total_puts_change_oi = 0;
  let total_calls_change_oi = 0;

  //* entry of all sp lying in range of 1000 points up and down
  const start = Math.max(0, atmIndex - 20);
  const end = Math.min(opDatas.length - 1, atmIndex + 20);
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    const element = opDatas[i];
    const sp = element.strike_price;

    //* suming up coi of 10 strikes up-down
    if (Math.abs(i - atmIndex) <= 10) {
      total_puts_change_oi += element.puts_change_oi;
      total_calls_change_oi += element.calls_change_oi;
    }
    //* storing coi of 20 strikes up-down in db
    const doc = await Symbol.findOne({ strikePrice: sp }).catch(errorHandler);
    const oiArray = {
      putsCoi: element.puts_change_oi,
      callsCoi: element.calls_change_oi,
    };

    if (!doc) {
      await Symbol.create({ strikePrice: sp, oiArray }).catch(errorHandler);
    } else {
      await Symbol.updateOne({ strikePrice: sp }, { $push: { oiArray } }).catch(
        errorHandler
      );
    }
  }
```

When I try to make API call for one single endpoint it works fine also sometimes within loop works fine, but what is the cause of error and how to overcome this?

Comment: You're not just calling it in a loop, you are firing off the requests all in parallel. If there's a large amount of symbols you are doing a *ton* of http requests at the same time and it's not unexpected for errors to occur.

Comment: in total there are 188 symbols, can you suggest how to implement?

Answer (score 0):

This causes all symbols to be fetch in sequence instead of parallel:

```js
const requests = [];
for(const element of symList) {
  requests.push(
    await axios.get(`${recordCoiCexUrl}/${element}`)
  );
};
```

Note that this will be slower. If the speed is not acceptable you could look into some libraries that allow for *some* parallelization, but I would probably not exceed 6.

Comment: after this do I need to use this :-

`await axios.all(requests).catch(errorHandler)`

Comment: I tried to use this and used await `axios.all(requests)` not only this I tried to use p-limit of 5 and then Promise.all() also but the error still persists please help me out, stuck on this since last 4 days.

Comment: @Chaser sorry! I forgot about the `await`. I added it in and this is what I meant to write. Note that `axios.all()` is deprecated and identical to `Promise.all()`

Comment: nope doesn't works I can share the repo with you if possible please help to get this done I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Doesn't work is not helpful debugging information!

Comment: I mean to say the ETIMEDOUT still persists

Comment: Are they at least happening in sequence? If yes and you're getting a timeout, the server might actually just not be reliable.

Comment: yes, they are happening in sequence and then time out but after time out when I try to manually get the endpoint it works so I don't think there is a request limit in the server. The server might not be reliable in which context?